# Insert data from Access table into ODBC link table (SQL server)

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access, odbc, ms-access-2010

I tried many solution to insert data from an Access table into an ODBC linked table (SQL Server).
The problem is ID Column table on SQL Server that link with ODBC link table is set identity.
So I can't insert ID Column from Access table. And I try to test 'set identity_insert ON' but it's not
work to insert via access query container or VBA.

Example VBA code

**Case 1 : Can insert**

```
Sub InsertData()
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    
    Dim strSQL As String
    
    ' Set up the INSERT INTO statement with a subquery
    strSQL = "INSERT INTO odbc_link_table_from_sql_server (col2) " & _
             "SELECT col2 FROM access_table"
    
    ' Execute the SQL statement
    CurrentDb.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError
    
    MsgBox "Data inserted successfully!"
    
    Exit Sub
    
ErrorHandler:
    Debug.Print err.description
End Sub
```

> //output : Data inserted successfully!

**Case 2 : Can not insert**

```
Sub InsertData()
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    
    Dim strSQL As String
    
    ' Set up the INSERT INTO statement with a subquery
    strSQL = "INSERT INTO odbc_link_table_from_sql_server (ID,col2) " & _
             "SELECT ID,col2 FROM access_table"
    
    ' Execute the SQL statement
    CurrentDb.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError
    
    MsgBox "Data inserted successfully!"
    
    Exit Sub
    
ErrorHandler:
    Debug.Print err.description
End Sub
```

> //output : An error occurred: ODBC--call failed.      48

Does anyone have solution to insert data?

I try to use `set identity_insert on` in access VBA and access query container but not work.
I expect to insert data in ID column on access table into ODBC link table. By the rule below

1. Do not alter or modify structure of SQL Server talble
2. Do not loop insert

Finally I expect to use Access query container to insert data.

Comment: you can't insert identity into linked table me thinks, because set insert_identity must be run on the local side of the query. But also, why would you want to. Re-think your design and either remove the identity part of the column so you can insert explicit values to your heart's contents, or just skip setting the identity column manually, so it's filled automatically

Comment: @siggemannen thank you for comment. Unfortunately. I can't edit the table on sql server that a requirement. And I want to use ID column from access_table because I use that column to extract data and reference other table in table access.

Comment: OK, but can someone else edit the table? is it used from several places?

Comment: @siggemannen it's test environment. I no idea about it used from several places. But
remove the identity part of the column that is only one solution?

Comment: siggemannen is correct - your requirements won't work. If only your Access DB inserts into this table, remove the IDENTITY, then you can insert the IDs from Access. -- If other programs insert into the table, their auto-generated IDs will sooner or later conflict with your IDs from Access, even if you solve your current problem.